# how to relocation dropdownmenu by CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, richfaces

I would like to set the location of DropDownMenu on the bottom of the header, as the item "Acceuil", and I used a css style. But it doesn't work. My code is as following: using the "styleClass="groupstyle" to adjust the location.

Is anybody knows how to fix the problem? Thanks for your response in advance.

```
<rich:toolBarGroup>
    <s:link id="menuHomeId" view="/home.xhtml" value="#{messages.Home}"
        propagation="none" styleClass="groupstyle"/>
</rich:toolBarGroup>

<rich:dropDownMenu showDelay="250" hideDelay="0" submitMode="none" styleClass="groupstyle">
    <f:facet name="label">ParamÃ¨tres</f:facet>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/UsersList.xhtml" value="Gestion des utilisateurs"
            id="UtilisateursId1" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/ImportData.xhtml" value="Import des donnÃ©es"
            id="ImportDonnees" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/ImExrtportLocaux.xhtml"
            value="Import/Export des locaux" id="ImpExrportLocaux"
            includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuGroup value="Export des donnÃ©es" direction="bottom-right">
        <rich:menuItem>
            <s:link view="/XLSOccupantList.seam" value="Export des occupants"
                id="ExporteOccupants" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
        </rich:menuItem>
        <rich:menuItem>
            <s:link view="/XLSOccupantList.seam" value="Export des occupants"
                id="ExporteOccupants2" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
        </rich:menuItem>
    </rich:menuGroup>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/ContactList.xhtml" value="Contact List"
            id="ContactId1" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/ReglagesList.xhtml" value="Reglages List"
            id="ReglagesId1" includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/DiversList.xhtml" value="Divers List" id="DiversId1"
            includePageParams="false" propagation="none" />
    </rich:menuItem>
    <rich:menuItem>
        <s:link view="/MessageAccList.xhtml" value="Message Acc" id="MessageAcc"
            includePageParams="false" propagation="none"/>
    </rich:menuItem>
</rich:dropDownMenu>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
.rich-toolbar, .rich-toolbar td {
background-color: #64BEC6;
height:120px;
}

.rich-toolbar-item, .rich-toolbar-item a {
background-color: #64BEC6;
height:50px;
}

.rich-toolbar-item a:hover {
text-decoration: underline; 
}

.rich-menu-item a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
}

.groupstyle{
    font-size:14px; 
position:relative; 
    bottom:-35px; 
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: Show us the CSS you have?...

Comment: I've added the css in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of the menu is defined on the `<div>` itself, e.g.

```
<div … style="z-index: 2; left: -7px; top: 2px; width: 119px; display: block;">
```

This means that any class rules will be overwritten. To prevent this use `!important` where necessary.

```
.groupstyle {
    font-size: 14px; 
    position: relative !important; 
    bottom: -35px !important; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```